# Can I change the window-switching animation without CCSM?

Tags: software-recommendation, compiz, animations

I want to use the coverflow animation during window switching between applications. I am very reluctant to use Compiz (with CCSM, to be specific) because it makes Ubuntu too slow.

I don't want any of the other Compiz animations or effects, I'm really only after the coverflow animation.

Is there any way I can enable this without Compiz? Are there any alternatives?

I have one other requirement: I need to be able to set the default window position (to center). Compiz/CCSM allows me to set that.

### EDIT

Well i just realised , i should have put, CCSM! not compiz! i dont want to remove compiz , i just want to NOT MAKE USE OF CCSM!

Comment: Are you using Unity and do you want to keep using Unity? If the answer to those is yes, the answer to your question is no. Unity requires Compiz.

Comment: oh... okay!the answer is yes...m using and want to use unity! :(

Comment: @Oli just edited the question.Have a look!

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that CCSM would make anything any slower because it's just editing existing Compiz settings. Compiz is still the compositor.

Comment: thats the same thing ive been thinking but it still happens! ive tested it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only alternatives I can think of involve switching compositor.

Before I go any further down that route you need to understand that Unity (the desktop environment that default Ubuntu ships with) depends completely on Compiz. If you use another compositor, you need another desktop environment.

Assuming you want me to continue, what we're actually looking for now is a replacement desktop environment. They're all substantially different to Unity so *I* can't tell you what *you* want. I use KDE, lots like Gnome and plenty use XFCE on lower-end hardware. There are many, many choices.

This question goes a distance to detail some of them:

- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: yeah... i got that it will need a change of DE... like the elementry os DE uses another compositor... but i dont intend to switch from unity! :( so i cant get that! umm...just a quick question, since unity depends on compiz, it already exists.but then y just the installation of CCSM makes ubuntu go slow? i mean its actually just an interface to manage compiz isnt it?